# How to import two versions of the same python module at the same time?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Suppose I have two versions of a python package, say "lib". One is in folder `~/version1/lib` and the other is in `~/version2/lib`. I'm trying to load both packages in one session by doing this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '~/version1')
import lib as a

sys.path.insert(0, '~/version2')
import lib as b
```

But it doesn't work, because of cache, `b` will be the same as `a`.

Is there anyway to do it? Maybe use hook in `sys.meta_path`? I didn't figure it out.

Or is there anyway to delete cache of imported modules?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? You accepted an answer but claimed it didn't work, so that was weird. I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: still looking for an answer ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- You can consider using [python virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).
- Activate the required environment and run your code there.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, i want to import two version of module **at the same time**. Plus, i was running this python in apache2 server, how to invoke the script is not controlled by me

Comment: I think someone who’s asking if `sys.meta_path` is a possible solution knows what a virtual environment is.

Answer (score 5):

You have to import it from one level higher:

```
import version1.my_lib as a
import version2.my_lib as b
```

Also make sure that in all the folder there is a `__init__.py`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible. Because inside `my_lib`, there will be some other files `import my_lib.XXX.XXX`. Your solution will cause inside import fail `ImportError: No module named my_lib.XXX.XXX`

Comment: It's not acceptable. I don't want to modify codes, actually these codes are not written by me

Answer (score 0):

Using the new `importlib` interfaces, this is possible relatively simply:

```
import sys
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec
from pathlib import Path


def secondary_import(path: Path, name: str = None):
    if name is None:
        name = path.with_suffix('').name

    old_modules = {n: m for n, m in sys.modules.items() if n == name or n.startswith(name + ".")}
    for n in old_modules:
        del sys.modules[n]

    spec =  spec_from_file_location(name, str(path))
    module = module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    our_modules = {n: sys.modules[n] for n in old_modules}
    sys.modules.update(old_modules)
    return module, our_modules
```

This can then be used like this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '~/version1')
import lib as a


sys.path.pop(0)

b, _ = secondary_import(os.path.join('~/version2', os.path.relpath(a.__path__, '~/version1')))
```

Note that this can easily break, especially if `lib` does anything weird with imports. This includes:

- Modifying truly global state (e.g. `sys.path`)
- Modifying global state of other modules
- Local relative imports inside of functions (like are sometimes used to fix circular dependencies)
- Dynamic imports
- Uses something from `importlib.resources` or `importlib.metadata`
- Non-basic-python files like C extensions or namespace packages

A few of these can be worked around, a few can't. I might create a package to see what can be done in a general way.

Comment: thanks that helped me to find an alternative solution which consisted in giving another name to a version within the sys.modules dic and importing