# How to load different version of caffe in a single python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am running two neural networks for my project, both of which use different versions of caffe. I am trying to add the path of the caffe module using the sys module. The first neural network runs without any difficulty, however the second neural network has problem regarding the path to its caffe module.

I have tried removing the caffe path location that i added earlier and then tried adding the caffe path for the second neural network. Then also it is giving me error.

The only solution i found is to run my second neural network in a subprocess. However it is not efficient as i have to save all the data in a file and then read and do the computation in the main process later.

I was suggested by someone to use environment variables but i don't know how to go along this concept.

Any help as how can i load multiple caffe version would be great.

**EDIT**

I have tried adding different versions of the modules using the logic given by **Shai** ex: Adding different versions of numpy. However the same logic doesn't work in the case of caffe.

```
import caffe_a as caffe_a, caffe_b as caffe_b
```

**error displayed** : WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0223 08:21:57.810040 17753 layer_factory.hpp:69] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 0 (1 vs. 0) Layer type Convolution already registered.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)

**Another approach tried and failed:**

I tried to use ***threading***, where i tried to load different caffe version in each independent thread. Now i don't get any error However only one version of caffe is getting loaded. Actually the `sys.modules` variables is globally shared between all the threads and thus when the second `import caffe` statement is executed, python just sees that the modules are already present and does not load the new caffe modules.

Are there any ways using which we can change the behaviour of the threads?

Comment: have you considered using threads instead of subprocess?

Comment: @Shai i have not used threads yet. Actually my neural networks are executed one after the another. Thus wanted to use a simple solution using which we can just load different caffe version using a single command in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import two versions of the same python module at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160625/how-to-import-two-versions-of-the-same-python-module-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @Shai it is not a duplicate question, To import and remove different python modules is way easier. I have tried adding multiple versions of numpy myself and it works perfectly. However for caffe it is not working. I have tried all possible cases and then have asked the question.

Comment: can you please **briefly** describe the methods you did try and why they did not work for caffe?

Comment: @Shai i tried the solution that you provided. I tried to run the other neural network in a separate process and it is working properly but i have to store the output images and then read it in the main process, which is increasing the throughput time( due ti IO operations). Thus i wanted to try to run both the neural networks together somehow without creating a subprocess.

Comment: @Shai , i have edited the question and have listed the error that is being displayed after trying the solution that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly an expert in python, but I'll give it a try...

I assume you have two folders `/path/to/caffe-a` and `/path/to/caffe-b` each of them is a clone of a different branch of caffe. Thus you have

```
/path/to/caffe-a/python/caffe/_caffe.so
/path/to/caffe-b/python/caffe/_caffe.so
```

And so on...

In order to distinguish between the two versions I suggest you create soft links:

```
~$ ln -s /path/to/caffe-a/python/caffe /path/to/caffe-a/python/caffe_a
~$ ln -s /path/to/caffe-b/python/caffe /path/to/caffe-b/python/caffe_b
```

In python, add both versions of caffe to path

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/caffe-a/python')
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/caffe-b/python')
```

Now import them with different names

```
import caffe_a as caffe_a, caffe_b as caffe_b
```

Build a net using `'a'` version

```
net_a = caffe_a.Net('/path/to/deploy.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
net_a.forward()
```

Build a net using `'b'` version:

```
net_b = caffe_b.Net('/path/to/other/deploy.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
net_b.forward()
```

Good luck...

Comment: it gave me this error:     WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0223 08:21:57.810040 17753 layer_factory.hpp:69] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 0 (1 vs. 0) Layer type Convolution already registered.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped) .    This error came when i tried import both of the caffe versions together(import caffe_a as caffe_a, caffe_b as caffe_b)

Comment: i have to execute both the neural networks together. The output of the first network is used by the second network and thus creating a virtual environment would not help. I know virtual environments are like containers having all the dependencies of a package. I don't have any idea as how can i use it for my task.